# Http.post error: map is not a function in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get data from url by http.post function. But I'm getting errors.
The source code of app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
 <div>
  <button (click)="postData()">Post Data</button>
  <p>Posted the following values:</p>
  <div>{{postResponse.id}}</div>
  <div>{{postResponse.name}}</div>
 </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
 result: Object;
 http: Http;
 postResponse = new Person();

 constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
 }

 postData(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://141.79.39.454:8008/the-link-something-like-this...', JSON.stringify({"id": 1, "name": "Новые"}),{headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
 }
}

class Person{
 id:number;
 name:string;
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

JSON in url looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDnh7.png)
When I click the button I'm getting the errors look like this:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function
at AppComponent.postData (http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:35:26)
at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_AppComponent_0.handleEventInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:10897:14), <anonymous>:124:33)
at AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8788:22)
at AppView.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9396:39)
at AppView.dispatchRenderEvent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9391:19)
at DefaultRenderView.dispatchRenderEvent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:7819:53)
at eventDispatcher (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9781:19)
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9852:14
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:15370:34
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:7874:18
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]run @ angular2-polyfills.js:143zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111
```

Comment: Post the stack trace as text, in the question, rather than a link to an image.

Comment: Could you look at it?

Comment: I think you're just using an old version of Angular2. Update to the latest beta.

Comment: I've installed the latest beta)

Comment: Then I have no idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to add the following in your imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Oh, errors disappeared! ) But now it doesn't show the results of request. Could it be connected with header or JSON.stringify?

Comment: A clue should be to have a look at the Network tab within Chrome dev tools for example to see if the request is executed and the response is there...